# Disabling screenshots and screen recording programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to block the screen recording and screen shot capturing for the videos that are being played in my app. I have used [FLAG_SECURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE), which doesn't allow to take screen shot but we could record the video though it shows a blank screen but audio is recorded.

Is there a way that I can also prevent the audio from being recorded?

Comment: You mean, that copying can only be done via the headphone plug; disabled internal recording by other app?

Comment: @Joop Eggen Thank you for the response firstly and yes, other apps should not record videos played in my app

Comment: @ShradhaGurjar got any working solution ? I'm also looking for a similar feature.